# Issues with cross-class methods and Objected Oriented Logic in Java

Tags: java, oop, methods

I'm in a beginners Java course, and I am working on my first object oriented assignment. I do understand the basics of OOP, but I don't have quite the knowledge required to put it into practice. If anyone could please point out any newbie mistakes or give me some pointers, I would be very grateful.

Here is the assignment:

Create class SavingsAccount. Use a private static class variable to store the annualInterestRate for each of the savers. Each object of the class contains a private instance variable savingsBalance indicating the amount the saver currently has on deposit. Provide method calculateMonthlyInterest to calculate the monthly interest by multiplying the balance by annualInterestRate divided by 12; this interest should be added to savingsBalance. Provide static method modifyInterestRate that sets the annualInterestRate to a new value. Write a driver program to test class SavingsAccount. Instantiate two different savingsAccount objects, saver1 and saver2, with balances of $2,000.00 and $4,000.00, respectively. Set annualInterestRate to 3%, then calculate the monthly interest and print the new balances for each of the savers. Then set the annualInterestRate to 5% and calculate the next month's interest and print the new balances for each of the savers.

Here is my current code:

```
class savings{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double annualInterestRate = 0;
        double monthlyInterest = 0;
        SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000, .03);
        SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(4000, .03);
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver1);
        System.out.println("Monthly Interest at 3%: " + monthlyInterest);
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver2);
        System.out.println("Monthly Interest at 3%: " + monthlyInterest);
        modifyInterestRate(saver1);
        modifyInterestRate(saver2);
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver1);
        System.out.println("Monthly Interest at 5%: " + monthlyInterest);
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver2);
        System.out.println("Monthly Interest at 5%: " + monthlyInterest);
    }
}

class SavingsAccount{
    static double annualInterestRate;
    static private double savingsBalance;
    public static double calculateMonthlyInterest(double annualInterestRate){
                double monthlyInterest = 0;
                monthlyInterest = savingsBalance * annualInterestRate / 12;
                return monthlyInterest;
        }
    public static void modifyInterestRate(double annualInterestRate){
        annualInterestRate = .05;
    }
    SavingsAccount(double savingsBalance, double annualInterestRate){
        this.savingsBalance = savingsBalance;
        this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    }
}
```

And here is the compiling errors:

```
F:\Archive\Homework_Spring_2014\Java\Project 2\Savings\savings.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver1);
        ^
  symbol:   method calculateMonthlyInterest(SavingsAccount)
  location: class savings
F:\Archive\Homework_Spring_2014\Java\Project 2\Savings\savings.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver2);
        ^
  symbol:   method calculateMonthlyInterest(SavingsAccount)
  location: class savings
F:\Archive\Homework_Spring_2014\Java\Project 2\Savings\savings.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        modifyInterestRate(saver1);
        ^
  symbol:   method modifyInterestRate(SavingsAccount)
  location: class savings
F:\Archive\Homework_Spring_2014\Java\Project 2\Savings\savings.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        modifyInterestRate(saver2);
        ^
  symbol:   method modifyInterestRate(SavingsAccount)
  location: class savings
F:\Archive\Homework_Spring_2014\Java\Project 2\Savings\savings.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver1);
        ^
  symbol:   method calculateMonthlyInterest(SavingsAccount)
  location: class savings
F:\Archive\Homework_Spring_2014\Java\Project 2\Savings\savings.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        calculateMonthlyInterest(saver2);
        ^
  symbol:   method calculateMonthlyInterest(SavingsAccount)
  location: class savings
6 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

I believe those errors are from methods being referenced across classes, but I don'y know the proper way to do it.

Comment: This "private **static** class variable to store the annualInterestRate **for each** of the savers" makes no sense.

Comment: static anything other than the main method makes no sense. Just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have several misconceptions about how to run a method on an object.

For instance, when you do this:

```
    SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000, .03);
    calculateMonthlyInterest(saver1);
```

You are not telling `saver1` to execute the `calculateMonthlyInterest`, but rather trying to invoke a method on the `savings` class, giving it `saver1` as an argument.

If you try this instead:

```
    SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000, .03);
    saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
```

you will still get an error, since for some reason you've made your `calculateMonthlyInterest` static, and take `annualInterestRate`, even though you already pass in the interest rate in the constructor of the object.

What you really want to do is something like this:

```
    double annualInterestRate = 0;
    double monthlyInterest = 0;
    SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000, .03);
    SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(4000, .03);
    monthlyInterest = saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    System.out.println("Monthly Interest at 3%: " + monthlyInterest);
    monthlyInterest = saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    System.out.println("Monthly Interest at 3%: " + monthlyInterest);
    // etc
```

While changing your method signature to this:

```
public double calculateMonthlyInterest(){
```

You have have the same problem in your other methods and the calls to them.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I always miss at least one major thing. I don't know what I was thinking, trying to pass it as an argument..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your ***everything*** is messed up.

- Make all SavingsAccount methods and fields non-static. All.
- Don't pass the SavingsAccount variables in to your method parameters as that makes no sense. Instead, call methods on the SavingsAccount instances, not the other way around.
- Pass in the correct parameters when calling methods the same parameter types that are used to define your methods.
- Read your book and check your notes, since you can't guess at this stuff, especially when starting out. It's a high hill that you must climb when starting programming, so use the assistance of your resource materials that you've got. They'll help you get over those peaks!

Comment: I did go a little crazy with the statics, I was experimenting a little. Thanks for your support, its easy to forget little things like that when starting out.